# Modified and redesign login page html in ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I am building an ASP.NET Core MVC web app targeting .NET Core 3.1.

I've enabled authentication type "Individual Accounts" and that created login and register pages.

When I run the project, I can see the link of my login page was

```
https://localhost:44344/Identity/Account/Login
```

but I can not find html login page in that path

```
Identity/Account/Login
```

Also I do search in my repo folder where my project is exists, still can't find it. There is nothing in my solution project ... there is only `_LoginPartial.cshtml`

[image: here is my solution explorer]

So where is this file stored?

And if it does not exist or is created dynamically in some way, how can I redesign the `login` or `register` html pages?

Comment: There should be an area `Identity` in your solution, and in the `Controllers`  folder of that area, you should find the `AccountController` with a `Login` method - which is what gets called when you hit this URL: That  is **very basic** ASP.NET MVC mechanism - I would recommend you learn a lot more about those basic workings of ASP.NET MVC before proceeding any further

Comment: thanks @marc_s for your comment. the AccountController is exist on **ASP.NET MVC** but not on **ASP.NET Core MVC**. I do every thing to reach it but cant find it.

Comment: Did my answer not work for you? Interested to know on this one.  The Pages you are after are baked into .NET Core.  So you’ll need to scaffold the ones you need to be able to get at them and modify them.

Comment: I did not understand your answer as i am new to asp.net

Comment: That’s OK.  If you right click on your project in the Solution Explorer and click Add.  Do you see an option for adding a New Scaffolded Item?

Comment: yes and then i did identity then there is a lot of pages so what is the next

Comment: You’ll need to select Account/Login & Account/Register as these are the ones you wish to modify.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233696/discussion-between-abdullah-bahattab-and-kev-ritchie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ll have to scaffold those pages.  I wrote a blog on it.

https://kevinritchie.co.uk/blazor/server/identity/2021/03/25/override-login-page-blazor-server-app.html

Essentially, you need to right click on your project and click Add.  Then select Add Scaffolded Item.

From the Add New Scaffolded Item window, select Identity.

You’ll get a few options to pick from.  You’ll need to select Account/Login and Account/Register.

Comment: I will try do it later as i tried this time runnig on error. i hope this will work again

Comment: Let me know how you get on.  Happy to help further.

Comment: @kev_Ritchie i can access the pages now  but when i chenged the layout its running error: **InvalidOperationException: The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered by the page at '/Views/Shared/_LayoutlandPage.cshtml': 'Scripts'. To ignore an unrendered section call IgnoreSection("sectionName").
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage.EnsureRenderedBodyOrSections()** so i create rendering as the default layout. then when i run the project the login page showing html objectives as there is no css effect. so can i redesign it

Comment: In the /Views/Shared/_Layouts.cshtml file, just before the closing body tag.  You can add **@await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)** if it's not already there.  This should resolve that error.

Comment: did you mean the /Views/Shared/_Layouts.cshtml or /Views/Shared/_LayoutlandPage.cshtml

Comment: /Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml

Comment: thanks. we can access the pages and modified the design with out errors.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the css file in `_LayoutlandPage.cshtml`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
```

Comment: of course its included. the index page works fine but login page does not.